# Voting to close your own question instead of deleting

Tags: discussion

Tonight I voted to close my own question as a duplicate when I could have deleted both my zero voted question and self answer.

The reason I did this was because my question title: [Why does `journalctl --list-boots` only show the current boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002524/why-does-journalctl-list-boots-only-show-the-current-boot) was substantially different than the duplicate target: [How to find previous boot log after Ubuntu 16.04 restarts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765315/how-to-find-previous-boot-log-after-ubuntu-16-04-restarts)

Was it ok to vote to close my own question rather than deleting it?

I think I was using "signpost quantum theory of Zanna"--or something like that :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### You did exactly the right thing

The whole network follows Zanna's opinion by now, see [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://askubuntu.com/help/duplicates):

> There are many ways to ask the same question, and a user might not be
> able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way. (…)
> Some
> duplicate questions may eventually be deleted, but often they are left
> as a signpost pointing people towards the canonical answer to that
> question.

Comment: An actual benefit of closing rather than deleting is (AFAIK) that a closed post will not count towards a question ban. More people should close their questions rather than remove them.